# how to assign labels to clusters in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a 50 point data set and i clustered it into three clusters and plot them.How we can label those clusters..

```
    symbs= {'r+','g.','bv','m*','ko'};
    figure;
    hold on
    for i = 1: length(I)
    plot(X(I(i),1),X(I(i),2),symbs{i},'MarkerSize',20)
    plot(X(C==i,1),X(C==i,2),symbs{i})

    end
```

I just want to give labels to those plotted clusters

Comment: @EitanT: wasn't me who downvoted, but I can see how it can be seen as "low quality"; for example the OP never explained what the variables `C` and `I` contained, and expects reader to have read his/her recent sequence of questions...

Comment: @Amro I agree that this question is not among the clearest, but it _can_ be improved with a little editing. Addressing to the downvoter, why being so harsh with new users instead of leaving a constructive comment?

Answer (score 2):

**Approach 1:** Create a [legend](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/legend.html)

```
symbs= {'r+','g.','bv','m*','ko'};
figure;
hold on
for i = 1: length(I)
    plot(X(I(i),1),X(I(i),2),symbs{i},'MarkerSize',20)
    plot(X(C==i,1),X(C==i,2),symbs{i})
end

labels = {'Cluster 1','Cluster 2','Cluster 3','Cluster 4','Cluster 5'};
legend(labels);
```

Since you're plotting two graphics objects with each symbol, you will (probably) find that
this doesn't look quite right: There will be two repetitions of each symbol in the legend rather than one.  To solve this, store the [handles](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/learn_matlab/f3-15974.html) of one of the sets of objects, and use the handles as the first argument to `legend`.

```
for i = 1: length(I)
    h(i) = plot(X(I(i),1),X(I(i),2),symbs{i},'MarkerSize',20);
    plot(X(C==i,1),X(C==i,2),symbs{i})
end

labels = {'Cluster 1','Cluster 2','Cluster 3','Cluster 4','Cluster 5'};
legend(h, labels(1:length(h)) );
```

**Approach 2:** Use [annotation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/annotation.html)

Annotation lets you do things like draw arrows or place text boxes containing identifying information onto your plots.  See the link for the options, and an example.